# how do i insert one value into two columns using ssis

Tags: ssis

i have one `excel file` and that is containing `price` column..

now i need to insert that `price` into table but same price should be inserted into two columns..

for example :

table :

```
companyname  initialprice lastprice 
ABC COPR     null         null
```

now i have used `excel file source` and `oledb destination`
but how can i map price to `initialprice` and `lastprice`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also just use a derived column and set the derivation for lastprice and initialprice to both be just the "price" column from excel.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just import it into the first column (initialprice) only and then run some SQL to copy the value to the second column after the import?

eg:`UPDATE table SET lastprice = initialprice`

Comment: but in ssis how can i do this using sql task i guess?

Comment: Through Execute SQL task indeed, but take care that you're only updating the freshly-inserted records (unless your destination table is always empty when the process starts)